# How to return a jagged array

Tags: c#, return, jagged-arrays

I have a function which use a 2D jagged array to save records from an SQL query.

How do return the jagged array correctly?

I tried something like:

```
public string[][] GetResult()
{
    return result;
}
```

And in my main programm:

```
string[][] test = new string[server1.GetResult().Length][];
test = server1.GetResult();
```

Well, as expected, it didn't work.

I don't know how to fix my problem.

Comment: The premise is correct, so there's something else going on -- the `string[][]` is not the problem. Error message please?

Comment: FYI assigning to `test` is pointless in the declaration, since it is overwritten by the call to `Gronforum.GetResult`. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I will return the content of the jagged array in my function, to my main programm. But the array in my main programm is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jagged arrays are simply arrays of arrays.

In your code:

```
string[][] test = new string[server1.GetResult().Length][];
test = Gronforum.GetResult();
```

You first assign a new array to `test`, then overwrite it with the return value from `GetResult()`. The code does the same as:

```
string[][] test = Gronforum.GetResult();
```

Now the `GetResult()` should return a `string[][]` - try this to get a feel of working with jagged arrays:

```
public string[][] GetResult()
{
    string[][] result = new string[2][];
    result[0] = new string[] { "1", "2" };
    result[1] = new string[2];
    result[1][0] = "a";
    result[1][1] = "b";
    return result;
}
```

You could supply a reference to the result of the SQL operation to that method so it has access to the data, to "convert" it to a `string[][]`.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same mistake twice! I overwrite the array the hole time... It was really empty. Wit string[][] test = server1.GetResult(); it works perfectly. I tested it with result[1][1] = "b";, her the function return the values corretly. Thanks, guys!