# C# Returning an array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, return

I have checked a previous question similar however the provided solution did not work for me, or perhaps I am overlooking something.  [How to return a jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430523/how-to-return-a-jagged-array)

My code is as follows:

```
class Grids
{
    int[][] grid;
    public grid[][] MakeGrid() 
    {
        grid = new int [4][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = new int[4] {0,0,0,0};
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid[i][a]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The error returned is as follows:

> .Grids.grid' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Your should return int[][] from your MakeGrid method, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some minor adjustments required in your `MakeGrid` method:

```
public int[][] MakeGrid()
{
    grid  = new int[4][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(grid[i][a]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: Sadiq hit the nail. You can't use your property as return type of your MakeGrid method.

Comment: In addition, put `int[][]`  in front of `grid`  and get rid of the global variable.